# Entity Framework - Update or Add

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to loop through a series of incoming records, check my database to see if they already exist and add or update them as appropriate. Im having little success.

```
    var listOfClientAccounts = model.MTAccounts.ToList(); // single DB query
    // for each of the users MTManager
    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        var clientInDb = listOfClientAccounts
                             .SingleOrDefault(c => c.Login == user.Login); // runs in memory
        var processedUser = ProcessUserRecord(user);
        //Check if the Account Login is already in the database
        if (clientInDb != null)
        {
            processedUser.MTAccountId = clientInDb.MTAccountId;
            var entry = model.Entry(processedUser);
                            model.Entry(processedUser).CurrentValues.SetValues(processedUser);
            entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
            Console.WriteLine(x + " : UPDATE : " + processedUser.Login + "(" + clientInDb.MTAccountId + ")");
        }
        else
        {
            //  Client does not exist add now
            model.MTAccounts.Add(processedUser);
            Console.WriteLine(x + " : ADD :" + processedUser.Login);

        }
    }


 model.SaveChanges();

 public MTAccount ProcessUserRecord(UserRecord user)
        {
            MTAccount DALUser = new MTAccount
            {
                BrokerServerId = 1,
                Login = user.Login,
                Group = user.Group
            };
            return DALUser;
        }
```

The crucial thing is that I want to keep the saveChanges call till the end of the loop as there may be hundreds of records to call, and I dont want to make hundreds of db calls.

there error is as follow:

> Member 'CurrentValues' cannot be called for the entity of type
>   'MTAccount' because the entity does not exist in the context. To add
>   an entity to the context call the Add or Attach method of
>   DbSet.

Comment: and what is the problem in your code?

Comment: With how you've structured this, it doesn't matter where SaveChanges is called, you'll STILL make hundreds of calls.  You need to batch insert/update, which isn't available natively in EF and requires extension libraries

Comment: What's your model? Surely you just take the model, and either add a new entity or edit the matched entity before calling `SaveChanges()` - Which you're doing? What's the problem?

Comment: @DavidL I don't think that's entirely true, it might execute _hundreds of statements_, but it will do that all within a single transaction on a single connection, rather than opening/executing/closing connections if you did it one at a time.

Comment: @CodingGorilla while yes, that is technically true, that also doesn't alleviate the OP's concern, which is that hundreds of calls/statements will still be made, regardless of where SaveChanges is called.  That said, your point is absolutely correct...calling it in loop would have even greater performance issues.

Comment: To clarify the database is on a remote server, so I want the transactions kept to a minimum, I understand that there will be statements generated for each change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I worked it out,

in the original code I had:

```
var entry = model.Entry(processedUser);
model.Entry(processedUser).CurrentValues.SetValues(processedUser);
```

which was trying to update the values of the processedUser
What I should have said was this:

```
model.Entry(clientInDb).CurrentValues.SetValues(processedUser);
```

which applied the changes to the original client from database

thanks for the comments.